# Why SpriteAnimation.onComplete do not trigger after restarting the game in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

In a game with Flame engine, Player has a dead animation which is falling slowly when its dead, I wait to play dead animation to pause the game engine and display game over overlay, it works correctly for the first time game starts, but after game over when I restart the game, `onComplete` callback doesn't triggers at all. Why?

```
deadSpriteAnimation.onComplete = () {
          GameModel.instance.pauseGameEngine();
          gameRef.overlays.add(GameOverOverlay.id);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the same `SpriteAnimation` object in the second run, which has already finished. Either you have to re-create the `SpriteAnimation` or `reset` it before you add it again.